# Positioning Background Images and Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, positioning, background-image

I've been working on coding a personal website from scratch in my free time, and have gotten the layout mostly looking like I wanted. But for the life of me, I cannot figure out why Firefox does not align the 'dropdown menu items' ('about', 'blog', etc.) BELOW the background image into the dark grey area like it does in Safari.

HTML Page (dropdown menu javascript not included):

```
<html lang="en">

<head>

 <title>The Hominis Inquiry</title>

 <link href="hominquiry.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

 <script language="javascript" src="hominquiry.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<!--<script type="text/javascript">
/*
function toggleSound()
 {if (button.checked) 
 {sound=true}
 else 
 {sound=false}}
*/ 
</script> -->

<body onload="folded()">

<h1>

<div class="title">

<img src="leftbmk.jpg" height="30%" width="15%" align="left" />

<img src="rightbmk.jpg" height="30%" width="15%" align="right" />

 <a href="index.htm" target="_top" onmmouseover="hominis_define()" title="Return to Homepage">

 <span class="title">The Hominis Inquiry</span><br/>

 A Perpetually Inchoate Exegesis about Ourselves
 </a>
</div>

</h1>

<h2>

<div class="about" id="about" onmouseover="unfold('about')" onmouseout="fold('about')">
<a href="about.htm" >
About
</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="about.htm#site" class="underline">The Site</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.htm#" class="underline">More Schpiel</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.htm#issues" class="underline">Preamble on Social Issues</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.htm#author" class="underline">The Author</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.htm#source">Open Source Projects</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="blog" id="blog" onmouseover="unfold('blog')" onmouseout="fold('blog')">
<a href="blog.htm">
Blog
</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="blog.htm#recent" class="underline">Current</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog.htm" class="underline">Search by Date</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog.htm" class="underline">Search by Topic</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog.htm" class="underline">Search by Blogger</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog.htm">All Blogs</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="research" id="research" onmouseover="unfold('research')" onmouseout="fold('research')">
<a href="lab.htm">
Academic Research/ <br/> Papers
</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="research.htm#recent" class="underline">Epistemology</a></li>
      <li><a href="research.htm#" class="underline">Research</a></li>
      <li><a href="research.htm#" class="underline">Essays</a></li>
      <li><a href="research.htm#" class="underline">Computer Simulation</a></li>
      <li><a href="research.htm#">More Fun Stuff</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="hypercourse" id="hypercourse" onmouseover="unfold('hypercourse')" onmouseout="fold('hypercourse')">
<a href="hypercourse.htm">
Hyper-Courses <br/> On Demand
</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="hypercourse/physics.htm" class="underline">Physics (Algebra-Based)</a></li>
      <li><a href="hypercourse/diffeq.htm#" class="underline">Differential Equations</a></li>
      <li><a href="hypercourse.htm#" class="underline">Other University Studies</a></li>
      <li><a href="hypercourse.htm#" class="underline">Discussions/Suggestions</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>

<div class="links" id="links" onmouseover="unfold('links')" onmouseout="fold('links')">
<a href ="links.htm">
Other Arbitrarily <br/> Awesome Links
</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="links.htm">Me being Chopped Liver</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="contact" id="contact" onmouseover="unfold('contact')" onmouseout="fold('contact')">
 <form id="startsearch">
 <a href>
 Contact
 </a> <br/><br/><br/>
 <input type="text" id="sbox" size="15" value="(under rennovation)"> 
 <input type="button" id="sbutt" value="Find"
 </form>
</div>


</h2>

<table border="2" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" align="center" valign="center">
<tr><image src="about.jpg"></tr> <tr><image src="blog.jpg"></tr></td>
<tr><image src="issues.jpg"></tr> <tr><image src="mybooks.jpg"></tr></td>
</table>

<div class="hiportal" id="hiportal">

<p>

Welcome to the HIportal

UPDATES<br/><br/>

<u>(4/1/10) - Site Launched</u>:<br/> 
This is not an April Fools' joke... well maybe somewhat. Because of my lofty ambition to write this website from scratch, 
the pages are currently, not the prettiest. Feedback from viewers will definitely be crucial throughout the development 
of this page; though it may be better to hold on to the comments until I get the site up to more functional scale (forseeing
how radically things will change during that process). I think I really just wanted the gratification of getting a site up 
to public view (wooOOOo!). Right now, the main features really are a draft of the 'about' page and a largely incomplete 
chapter 2 of my physics e-book for high school students. Keep checking back for updates, of which there will be many these upcoming
few weeks...<br/>

Goals in sight: Keep this page alive, Upload fuller versions of ebook chapters 2-3
Long-term Technical: Implement a wiki engine to allow additions of news events by registered users

</p>

</div>

Trouble reading this site? Download the latest version of your preferred browser below...

</body>

</html>
```

This is the CSS:

```
body {background-color:#606060; color:white}
h1 {background-color:#606060; color:white; background-image:url(hicon_beta.jpg); font-size:100%; text-align:center; font-weight:700; text-decoration:none; font-family:Verdana}
h2 {color:#0000A0; background-color:#FFCCCC; font-size:200%; text-align:center; font-style:italic; font-weight:700; font-family: MS Gothic}
h3 {color:black; background-color:#DDDDDD}
div.title {position:absolute; left:0%; width:100%; text-align:center; background-image:url(hicon_beta.jpg); cursor:help}
 span.title {color:maroon; font-size:300%; font-weight:900; font-family:papyrus; text-align:center}
div.about {position:absolute; top:31.2%; bottom:34%; left:5%; width:15%; color:red; font-size:50%; text-align:center; z-index:1; overflow:hidden}
div.blog {position:absolute; top:31.2%; bottom:34%; left:21%; width:15%; color:red; font-size:50%; text-align:center; z-index:1; overflow:hidden}
div.research {position:absolute; top:31.2%; bottom:34%; left:37%; width:15%; color:red; font-size:50%; text-align:center; z-index:1; overflow:hidden}
div.hypercourse {position:absolute; top:31.2%; bottom:34%; left:53%; width:15%; color:red; font-size:50%; text-align:center; z-index:1; overflow:hidden}
div.links {position:absolute; top:31.2%; bottom:34%; left:69%; width:15%; color:red; font-size:50%; text-align:center; z-index:1; overflow:hidden}
div.contact {position:absolute; top:31.2%; bottom:34%; left:85%; width:10%; color:red; font-size:50%; text-align:center; z-index:1; overflow:hidden}
div.hiportal {position:absolute; top:35%; bottom:100%; left:10%; width:80%; background-color:silver}
p {background-color:silver; color:#220088; font-weight:500; text-align:left}
a:link {text-decoration:none; color:red}
a:visited {text-decoration:none; color:red}
a:hover {background-color:#FFFFDD; text-decoration:none}
dropdown.menu {background-color:#606060; color:#FFFFDD}
```

Sorry about the messy code. If anyone can shed light on what the problem might be here though, that would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: i'd really help if you could put your code online so we could debug it...

Comment: A Standards Mode DOCTYPE is also essential to limiting browser differences.

Comment: pleasedontbelong: web.pdx.edu/~jstraus/ (note the dropdown items are ON the background pictures rather than below it :P) thanks!

Comment: bobince: What doctype is currently 'standard' now? Most of my html/javascript learning is from a book dating back to '03 and a few w3c articles :(

Comment: You seem to have quite a few issues that need to be cleaned up. You're not really using the heading tags properly, they are meant for text and text stream items rather than code block containers. You're also using absolute positioning without defining the parent containers positioning. It doesn't look like you really need to absolute positioning in that case. Take a look at w3schools.com for some more current HTML and CSS tutorials. You should also run your pages through a validator like http://validator.w3.org/ to help find your problems.

Comment: While you are at it, I would also not recommend the use of frames. You can accomplish the same thing without using frames. I also notices that you are setting the height and width of the images in the header with percentages, your aspect ratio is getting killed as the browser window changes sizes. Try resizing your browser, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I was thinking about static positioning as an alternative (at least for the frameset layout). Does this sound like a reasonable approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you seem to know a lot about HTML and CSS, there are things you have to correct. Among others, you have to add a document type.

I found the tutorials at HTML Dog very useful when I started learning HTML and CSS. Even though you're clearly not a beginner, I suggest you start at http://htmldog.com/guides/htmlbeginner/ to learn about, among others, document type and character encoding.

Also, as is already pointed out above, use http://validator.w3.org A LOT to make sure your code is valid. It's not fool-proof but at least the most fool-proof HTML validator I have seen.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that this is your site: http://web.pdx.edu/~jstraus/

It seems that you're right when you say that you've got all your knowledge of HTML and CSS from a few old books and the W3School (please **do not** go there to learn HTML + CSS. The site itself is a collection of bad practices and don't do's).

First of all, please learn HTML and CSS from a good and up to date source. The [Web Standards Curriculum](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/1-introduction-to-the-web-standards-cur/) is a great place to start - it places a heavy emphasis on creating valid and standard compliant code, and also introduces some basics on designing websites. If you need references, try [Sitepoint References](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html). [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/) is also on most of our must-read list - try starting with older articles, from 2001- 2005.

The fact is, and I have to be blunt here, you website's code really doesn't belong in this era. Using tables for layout, frames, repeating backgrounds and really bad color and font choices just won't cut it now. If you want to learn HTML and CSS, hit the links I've mentioned above. If you just want an easy way to publish your thoughts or otherwise, consider installing a CMS/blogging platform like [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/) instead.

Comment: I didn't know about the site Web Standards Curriculum. It seems interesting. Maybe not for HTML and CSS beginners, though. At least I would have become overwhelmed had I started learning HTML and CSS there. I recommend http://htmldog.com/ for beginners (see answer above).

Comment: @matsolof I don't see why not - overwhelming wouldn't be the word I would use here. Placing a greater emphasis on the nature of web standards is extremely important - so much so that I would say that one really shouldn't do any coding before understanding that.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm looking through the articles right now. So far, the big things I'm grasping are the systematic use of the strict doctypes and using external files whenever remotely practical (the latter which I actually implemented yesterday, web.pdx.edu/~jstraus/Test/index.htm, though otherwise it's essentially unchanged). I'll let you know if html stuff "overwhelms" me :)

Comment: Yi Jiang, I agree with you in principle. However, you must also consider personality. When I start learning a new subject, I need to see some concrete results first, like writing a paragraph to an HTML file and see the text appear on the screen when I open the file with a browser, adding some CSS and see the background turn red, etc. When I've done that for a while, I can start reading articles like the ones at Web Standards Curriculum. I just started learning C#. Whenever I try reading a longer article about C#, I feel overwhelmed. I can't think of a better way to descibe it.

Comment: Jonathan Straus, I'm glad Yi Jiang provided links that obviously are for you, which I obviously didn't (sorry about that). Good luck!

Comment: matsolof: It's all good. To be honest, I agree with your position that the ideas in that article are kind of dry in themselves, and I would totally lose patience and probably quit if that was my first exposure to html coding. Only after bashing my head against cumulative problems of scale that I'm appreciating it so much. I might find good stuff in html dog after I'm done sifting through the other stuff :)

Comment: Jonathan Straus, I'm glad to hear I wasn't all wrong. One reason for checking out http://htmldog.com may be that it teaches how to write XHTML 1.0 Strict, a more modern version of HTML, used by, amongst others, http://www.w3.org. One difference is that more is done with CSS than in earlier versions of HTML.